# get a single attribut name in my ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, win-universal-app

I have a problem in setting the "name" text into my comboBox from a web Service,in fact I get a double of each name in my comboBox,this is my code:

```
 private async void getCategories()
        {
                Uri = "myWebService";
                http = new HttpClient();
                http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
                var response = await http.GetStringAsync(Uri);
                var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);
                List<Categories> v = rootObject1.categories.ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < v.Count; i++) { 
                    this.categoryCombo.Items.Add(v[i].name);
                       }
                this.categoryCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                     }
```

this is my web Service:

```
success: 1,
message: "categorie trouve!",
total: 2,
categories: [
{
id: "1",
name: "resto",
descr: "restaurant pizza"
},
{
id: "2",
name: "test",
descr: "test"
}
]
```

how can I correct my code to not have double of each name in my comboBox,I think my code is correct but I get always a double value in my combobox >_<

this is the result
[image]
thanks for help

Comment: I don't know about services, but just got a clue that your comboBox add your items more than one time. are you sure that your comboBox is empty when you add items in it?? 
if not then clear comboBox Items before adding new categories into it.
I hope it helps

Comment: set break point to your getCategories() method and make sure that it is does not called 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your getCategories is called 2 times. just set the breakpoint and see if it hits 2 times. But to make sure that your combobox contains one item just clear it before adding items here is the code.

```
   private async void getCategories()
    {
            Uri = "myWebService";
            http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(Uri);
            var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);
            List<Categories> v = rootObject1.categories.ToList();

            this.categoryCombo.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Count; i++) { 
                this.categoryCombo.Items.Add(v[i].name);
                   }
            this.categoryCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                 }
```

Comment: thanks Sir your solution works perfectly,Indeed I should clear the comboBox items :)